# override jquery hide() using inline css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

HTML

```
<div class="dep-adm-inp" <?php if(!empty($adm_f) || $adm_f != "") echo "style='display:block'"; ?> id="fees-inp">
    <label>Admission Fees(<i class="fa fa-inr"></i>)</label>
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon remove-inp"><i class="fa fa-close"></i></span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control expected" value="<?php if(!empty($adm_f)) echo $adm_f; ?>" placeholder="Amount Expected">
        <input type="text" class="form-control paid" value="<?php if(!empty($adm_f)) echo $adm_f; ?>" placeholder="Paid Amount">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
$(".dep-adm-inp").hide();
```

the div is hidden when page loads but if the php variable is not empty then i want to show the div when.

Comment: You can set the !important to your style to override. Try with this `style='display:block !important;'`

Comment: Unfortunately, `style='display:block !important;'` **inline** style will be overwritten by `hide()`. The style with the `important` property must be declared on a stylesheet (whether in a separate file or, possibly generated dynamically on the same page).

Answer (score 2):

set the class variable `dep-adm-inp` as hidden by default in css. If the variable `$adm_f` is not empty, set `style='display:block;'`.  With this logic you don't need to call the statement `$(".dep-adm-inp").hide();` in your javascript. This way the div will be shown only if the variable `$adm_f` is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

`.hide()` method sets `display:none;` on your element. 
You can override it by setting `display: block!important;` (or whatever your `display` property is) in CSS:

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  $('.item').hide();
}, 2000);
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.item {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: darkgoldenrod;
  margin: 10px;
}


/* This makes .item visible even after .hide() */

.item-visible {
  display: block!important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="item item-visible">Will be visible</div>
  <div class="item">Will be hidden</div>
</div>
```